# Eloquent joins and queries in different databases on Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

How do I run this simple Mysql query in Laravel, from two different databases?

```
SELECT * FROM database1.table1, database2.table2
```

And how I do joins in Eloquent on different databases?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#joins

Comment: Hackerman - Multiple Databases? I dont think so...

Comment: If the databases are on the same server and the mysql user has access to both databases, you should be able to do it without any issues. You may just need to use `DB::raw`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned, if the databases are on the same server and the mysql user has access to both databases, you can pass the tables in with `DB::raw`:

```
$q1 = DB::table(DB::raw('database1.table1 AS db1_tb1'))->select('*');
$results = DB::table(DB::raw('database2.table2 AS db2_tb2'))->select('*')
->union($q1)
->get();
```

For a join:

```
DB::table(DB::raw('database1.table1 AS db1_tb1'))
   ->join(DB::raw('database2.table2 AS db2_tb2'),'db1_tb1.first_key','=','db2_tb2.second_key')
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use different connections to do that, so you should do something like:

```
$result = DB::connection('database1')->table('contacts')->get()
            ->union(
                DB::connection('database2')->table('contacts')->get()
            );
```

And if your Query Builder is does not return collections:

```
$result = collect(DB::connection('database1')->table('contacts')->get())
            ->union(
                collect(DB::connection('database2')->table('contacts')->get())
            );
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! And how to do JOIN in multi databases? Just manually?